# How is $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{2x}{n}+\frac{x^2+y^2}{n^2})^{\frac{n}{2}}=e^{\lim_{n\to \infty }(x+\frac{x^2+y^2}{2n})}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

How is $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{2x}{n}+\frac{x^2+y^2}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}=\exp\left({\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(x+\frac{x^2+y^2}{2n}\right)}\right)$$

I can only go far as (which Im not sure is the right direction)

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{2x}{n}+\frac{x^2+y^2}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}&=\exp\left({\lim_{n\to \infty}{\ln\left(1+\frac{2x}{n}+\frac{x^2+y^2}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}}}\right)\\&=\exp\left({\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{2}{\ln\left(1+\frac{2x}{n}+\frac{x^2+y^2}{n^2}\right)}}\right)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Taylor series yields $$\ln(1+a) = a - a^2/2 + a^3/3 \pm \ldots$$
so for very small $a$, since $a^2 << a$, you can approximate $\ln(1+a) \approx a$

**UPDATE**

Assume the limit on the LHS exists and let

$$
L = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{2x}{n}+\frac{x^2+y^2}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}
$$
Then, since $\ln(x)$ is continuous,
$$
\begin{split}
\ln L
  &= \lim_{n\to \infty}
        \ln \left[\left(1+\frac{2x}{n}
                         +\frac{x^2+y^2}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}\right]\\
  &= \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{2}
                       \ln \left(1+\frac{2x}{n}+\frac{x^2+y^2}{n^2}\right)\\
  &\approx \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{2}
                              \left[ \frac{2x}{n}+\frac{x^2+y^2}{n^2} \right]\\
  &= \lim_{n\to \infty} \left[ x+\frac{x^2+y^2}{2n} \right]
\end{split}
$$
and now exponentiating both sides yields the result.

Comment: Can you elaborate, I still cannot see

Comment: @BozoVulicevic see update

Answer (score -2):

If $(a_m)$ converge,
$$\lim_{m\to\infty }\lim_{n\to\infty }\left(1+\frac{2a_m}{n}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}=\lim_{m\to\infty }e^{a_m}=e^{\lim_{m\to\infty }a_m}.$$

It's a consequence of the fact that $$\lim_{n\to\infty }\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=e^x$$
for all $x$.

Set $a_m=x+\frac{x^2+y^2}{2m}$ to get the result.

Comment: Why downvoted ?